# REST Rails 2 nested routes without resource names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 2.
I have resources nested like this:
- university_categories
  - universities
    - studies
      - professors
        - comments

I wish to use RESTful routes, but I don't want all that clutter in my URL. For example instead of:
/universities/:university_id/studies/:study_id/professors/:professor_id
I want:
/professors/:university_id/:study_id/:professor_id
(I don't map professors seperately so there shouldn't be a confusion between this and /professors/:professor_id since that route shouldn't exist).
Again, I want to use RESTful resources/routes...
Also note, I am using slugs instead of IDs. Slugs for studies are NOT unique, while other are. Also, there are no many-to-many relationships (so if I know the slug of a professor, which is unique, I also know which study and university and category it belongs to, however I still wish this information to be in the URI if possible for SEO, and also it is necessary when adding a new professor). I do however want to use shallow nesting for "administrator" URIs like edit, destroy (note the problem here with Study since it's slug is not unique, though)...

I would also like some tips on how to use the url helpers so that I don't have too much to fix if I change the routes in the future...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like `map.resources` will provide you with this functionality, but you could use something like (untested)

```
map.show_professor "/professors/:university_id/:study_id/:professor_id", :controller => "professors", :action => "show"
```

and then similar routes for the other actions.

There might be a better solution, but this is the only way I can find that would work, since it seems map.resources assumes it is in the form of /resources/(:resource_id)

You can use REST this way, you just have to do all the actions yourself instead of using the shortcut.

As an example of an edit, you can just use

```
map.edit_professor "/professors/:id/edit", :controller => "professors", :action => "edit"
```

Comment: That's the way I had my routes done before, but I wanted to clean up a bit. So I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: I think you have to do this manually for now or put it into Rails itself.